# Limit groups of results based on a column value

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, mysql-8.0, limits

I'm not sure I formulated the question properly, but anyway.

I have a table with level-2 comments, some of which, expectedly, have the same `comment_parent` column value. How do I make a `SELECT` query that would limit results for rows with the same `comment_parent` to 5? So that I don't get 5 comments in total, but instead get 5 comments for each group of comments with the same `comment_parent` value?

I found a lot of (kind of) similar questions both here and on SO, but all those situations were different in one way or another, or I just wasn't able to "project" the answers from there to my case. So forgive me if this is just another duplicate in your opinion. I would really like to get an answer for my case precisely.

Table sample:

```
CREATE TABLE `level_2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_photo` varchar(2083) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2083) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_text` varchar(16834) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Data sample:

```
INSERT INTO `level_2` (`id`, `comment_id`, `comment_parent`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `user_photo`, `url`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`) VALUES
(1, 270, 269, 11223344, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(2, 271, 269, 22334455, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(3, 272, 269, 33445566, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(4, 273, 269, 11111111, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(5, 274, 269, 22222222, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(6, 275, 269, 11111111, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(7, 276, 269, 22222222, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(8, 280, 268, 35990230, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(9, 281, 268, 35990230, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(10, 282, 278, 35990230, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52');
```

My query so far:

`SELECT * FROM level_2 LIMIT 5`

The output I'm getting (roughly):

```
(`id`, `comment_id`, `comment_parent`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `user_photo`, `url`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`) VALUES
(1, 270, 269, 11223344, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(2, 271, 269, 22334455, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(3, 272, 269, 33445566, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(4, 273, 269, 11111111, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(5, 274, 269, 22222222, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45');
```

The output I'd like to get (roughly):

```
(`id`, `comment_id`, `comment_parent`, `user_id`, `user_name`, `user_photo`, `url`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`) VALUES
(1, 270, 269, 11223344, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(2, 271, 269, 22334455, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(3, 272, 269, 33445566, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(4, 273, 269, 11111111, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(5, 274, 269, 22222222, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(8, 280, 268, 35990230, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52'),
(9, 281, 268, 35990230, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-22 04:04:45'),
(10, 282, 278, 35990230, 'Username', '/userpic.jpg', '/example_page', 'sample text', '2019-02-27 12:27:52');
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it can help in this case, but ok. Please see the edit.

Comment: What should happen if the first 5 rows ('SELECT * FROM level_2 LIMIT 5') returns duplicated comment_parent values?

Comment: Nothing. I just need to output groups of the maximum of 5 rows with duplicated comment_parent values. That's my goal.

Comment: I'm using Mysql 8.

//P.S. the results must include rows without that duplicating value as well, but those duplicated must be limited to 5 per each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it because on-line fiddle do not has the last version, but if you are on MySQL 8.0.14 you could try by using a [LATERAL](https://mysqlserverteam.com/support-for-lateral-derived-tables-added-to-mysql-8-0-14/) join:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT comment_parent
     FROM level_2) cp,
LATERAL
    (SELECT *
     FROM   level_2
     WHERE  comment_parent = cp.comment_parent
     LIMIT 5) l2
;
```

If not, you could try with ROW_NUMBER:

```
WITH CT AS
(
    SELECT *,
           row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY comment_parent) rn
    FROM   level_2
)
SELECT * 
FROM   CT
JOIN   (SELECT DISTINCT comment_parent FROM level_2 LIMIT 5) cp
ON     CT.comment_parent = cp.comment_parent
WHERE  rn <=5 ;
```

> ```
> id | comment_id | comment_parent |  user_id | user_name | user_photo   | url           | comment_text | comment_date        | rn | comment_parent
> -: | ---------: | -------------: | -------: | :-------- | :----------- | :------------ | :----------- | :------------------ | -: | -------------:
>  8 |        280 |            268 | 35990230 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-27 12:27:52 |  1 |            268
>  9 |        281 |            268 | 35990230 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-22 04:04:45 |  2 |            268
>  1 |        270 |            269 | 11223344 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-22 04:04:45 |  1 |            269
>  2 |        271 |            269 | 22334455 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-27 12:27:52 |  2 |            269
>  3 |        272 |            269 | 33445566 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-27 12:27:52 |  3 |            269
>  4 |        273 |            269 | 11111111 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-27 12:27:52 |  4 |            269
>  5 |        274 |            269 | 22222222 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-22 04:04:45 |  5 |            269
> 10 |        282 |            278 | 35990230 | Username  | /userpic.jpg | /example_page | sample text  | 2019-02-27 12:27:52 |  1 |            278
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9fcd28ce8089ed0079c7c73937bbc420)*

Comment: Thank you! The first variant worked, except I had to remove the first occurence of `LIMIT 5` from the query, otherwise it would limit the whole response to 5 groups of comments, while I needed infinite groups each limited to 5 results. Please edit and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer, have a look.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example how to order each group of results by comment_id? I managed to make it output the _appropriate_ group of comments (the last 5) by using `SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT comment_parent FROM level_2 WHERE url = '".$url."') cp, LATERAL (SELECT * FROM level_2 WHERE url = '".$url."' AND comment_parent = cp.comment_parent ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 5) l2`, however, I also need each group of last 5 comments to be DESC ordered. Can't figure how to achieve this.